# Rock Paper Javascript trouble

Tags: javascript

I have looked through quite a few of the posts regarding rock, paper, scissors, but I am still unable to find a clear solution. I am relatively new, just trying to fully understand what I'm doing.

I have gone back and forth through this with a few different approaches. Therefore, I fear that there are inconsistencies in the code structure.

I am mostly stuck right now with updating the scoreboard and trying to update playerChoice from the DOM. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you all.

```
const player = {
    currentChoice: null,
    playerScore: 0
}

const computer = {
    currentChoice: null,
    computerScore: 0
}

const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];
player.currentChoice = choices[0]

function computerChooses() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex]
}

//using dot-method to access the array

function compareChoices() {
    computerChooses();
    if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
        postResult("It's a tie! Both players chose " + player.currentChoice);

        //conditionals computer against player
    } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
        if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
            postResult("The Player wins.");
            player.playerScore += 1
        } else {
            postResult("The Computer wins.");
            computer.computerScore += 1
        }
    } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
        if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
            postResult("The Player Wins")
            player.playerScore += 1
        } else {
            postResult("The Computer wins.");
            computer.computerScore += 1
        }
    } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
        if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
            postResult("The Player wins.");
            player.playerScore += 1
        } else {
            postResult("The Computer wins.")
            computer.computerScore += 1
        }
    }
}

function postResult(results) {
    const resultText = document.createElement('p');
    resultText.innerText = results;
    document.body.appendChild(resultText);
}

compareChoices();

function weaponSelect() {
    document.getElementById
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', buttonSelect)
buttonSelect();
```

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: How do I update the score to the scoreboard. I am supposed to use the DOM to updated the player score on click, and Im just a little lost. What I have here doesn't seem to be working and I am fairy certain that I have criss-crossed a few things and the code is likely inconsistent. So Im just looking for a bit of clarity.

Comment: you shouldn't use `+= 1` as it will always be `1` no matter the outcome, and if you are playing over and over, do the SUM on the loop, and not inside a function that should only return the winner ... a function should do only one thing, so you can easily re-use it...

Answer (score 0):

from your example, I took the liberty to change things a bit by creating a function to hold the core game, and then call it to play 10 times and show the result

**the idea** is to divide the use of the game from the game implementation as it should not be the game concern to count how many times a player won, the game should focus only on running the game itself, that **is the most basic principle of programming** together with DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself)...

I start with the implementation by using the [javascript Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that wraps all the game should do...

- will hold the 3 variables
- will be able to automatically choose an option
- as well ask for one
- and passing 2 options, will determine the winner

Then I started by using it to run `10` times and calculate the winner for each time... completely independent from the game it self.

I've commented the code, let me know if something's off...

```js
// game
class RpsGame {
  constructor() {
    this.options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    [this.ROCK, this.PAPER, this.SCISSORS] = this.options;
  }

  // will ask the player for a manual input
  askPlayerSelection = () => {
    var s = null;
    while (s == null) {
      s = prompt(`What do you want to play? press 1: ${ROCK} 2: ${PAPER} 3: ${SCISSORS}`);
      try { 
        s = parseInt(s, 10); // convert to integer
        if (!Number.isInteger(s) || s < 1 && s > 3) s = null; // has to be valid
      }
      catch(err) { s = null; } // if not valid, set as null so it asks again
    }
    return this.options[s-1];
  }

  // automatically assign an option
  getAutoPlayerSelection = () => {
    var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // betwen 0 and 2
    return this.options[s];
  }

  // calculates the winner between player1 and player2
  calculateWinner = (player1, player2) => {
    // same
    if (player1 === player2) return 'DRAW';
    // p1 has rock
    else if (player1 === this.ROCK) {
      if (player2 === this.PAPER) return 'player2';
      if (player2 === this.SCISSORS) return 'player1';
    }
    // p1 has paper
    else if (player1 === this.PAPER) {
      if (player2 === this.ROCK) return 'player1';
      if (player2 === this.SCISSORS) return 'player2';
    }
    // p1 has scissors
    else {
      if (player2 === this.PAPER) return 'player1';
      if (player2 === this.ROCK) return 'player2';
    }
  }
}

// #############################################################################################

// let's start the game engine
var engine = new RpsGame();
var selection = { rounds: [], player1: 0, player2: 0 };

// let's play 10 times
for (var i=1; i<10; i += 1) {
  
  var player1 = engine.getAutoPlayerSelection(); // change to engine.askPlayerSelection if manual input
  var player2 = engine.getAutoPlayerSelection();
  var winner = engine.calculateWinner(player1, player2);

  selection.rounds.push(winner); // save the winner
  if (winner !== 'DRAW') selection[winner] += 1; // append
}

// put result in the HTML
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(selection, null, 2);
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #eef;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

in order to test, click **Run code snippet** as many times you want to run the 10 times